# Typescript changes not compiling after git merge

Tags: git, visual-studio, typescript, webpack

I am working in a small team environment. When I merge in a change from a separate branch and try to recompile, the compiler doesn't notice any changes to the files affected by the merge. After manually editing the affected files (adding or removing a space) the compiler picks up the changes. This means for every merge I am manually opening several typescript files and add or removing a space to get my compiler to notice the changes. Has anyone ever had this issue?

I am using Visual Studio 2017. Compiling using Webpack.

Comment: Fascinating.  Are you doing the merge on the command-line or within Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm using SourceTree which is basically just GUI for command-line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out we were having this problem because I had a misunderstanding of how webpack was working. I thought webpack was both converting the typescript files to js and compiling them. Webpack was instead only looking for the .js files in the directory to compile.

Since we don't keep the .js files in the repository none of the changes were being picked up. Modifying the typescript files manually (adding or removing a space) worked because we have Visual Studio set to auto recompile the typescript files on save. Running "tsc" from the command line after a merge recompiles all the typescript files in the directory. Problem solved!